# Jenkins - Bad Message 431 reason: Request Header Fields Too Large

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm getting such message while viewing log output in ongoing job execution:

```
Bad Message 431

reason: Request Header Fields Too Large
```

It shows up on each job, no matter what logs are produced. It happens ~1 second after clicking console button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's known issue described here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25046
and fixed in 2.184 (https://jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.184).

So you can upgrade your Jenkins master or try deleting cookies in your browser.

Comment: I don't have access to Jenkins master, but deleting cookies helped! Thans a lot!

Comment: The issue you have linked looks to be 413 error(cookie header) instead of 431 error(request header). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Seems to be back in 2.303.1